# Solving simultaneous equations with R

Tags: r, equation-solving

Suppose I have the following equations:

```
 x + 2y + 3z = 20  
2x + 5y + 9z = 100  
5x + 7y + 8z = 200
```

How do I solve these equations for `x`, `y` and `z`? I would like to solve these equations, if possible, using R or any other computer tools.

Comment: also, I think "ternary" may not be the most descriptive term.  I would call this "a set of three coupled linear equations"

Comment: Along with Ben's comment, re-write it as a matrix equation.

Answer (score 33):

This should work

```
A <- matrix(data=c(1, 2, 3, 2, 5, 9, 5, 7, 8), nrow=3, ncol=3, byrow=TRUE)    
b <- matrix(data=c(20, 100, 200), nrow=3, ncol=1, byrow=FALSE)
round(solve(A, b), 3)

     [,1]
[1,]  320
[2,] -360
[3,]  140
```

Comment: If you plug the values 120, 0, -20 back into the equations this is incorrect.  It is correct if `byrow = TRUE`.

Comment: Did you? It does still have `byrow = FALSE`

Comment: @MYaseen208 What if my system of equations is transcendental?

Comment: Is solve the most efficient way to do this? What if the matrix is very big? Or the condition is low?

Answer (score 13):

For clarity, I modified the way the matrices were constructed in the previous answer.

```
a <- rbind(c(1, 2, 3), 
           c(2, 5, 9), 
           c(5, 7, 8))
b <- c(20, 100, 200)
solve(a, b)
```

In case we need to display fractions:

```
library(MASS)
fractions(solve(a, b))
```

Answer (score 5):

Another approach is to model the equations using `lm` as follows:

```
lm(b ~ . + 0, 
   data = data.frame(x = c(1, 2, 5), 
                     y = c(2, 5, 7), 
                     z = c(3, 9, 8), 
                     b = c(20, 100, 200)))
```

which produces

```
Coefficients:
   x     y     z  
 320  -360   140
```

If you use the `tibble` package you can even make it read just like the original equations:

```
lm(b ~ . + 0, 
   tibble::tribble(
     ~x, ~y, ~z,  ~b,
      1,  2,  3,  20,
      2,  5,  9, 100,
      5,  7,  8, 200))
```

which produces the same output.

Comment: Is there any benefit to this method? Precision? Computation speed?

Comment: I have not done any benchmarking, but if I were to guess directly using matrices is probably the fastest. However, I use the `lm` approach if it helps explain the purpose of my code. This is clearly a vague criterion; in my case if `x`, `y`, and `z` are variables or factors in my analysis then I may use `lm`.

Answer (score -3):

```
A <- matrix(data=c(1, 2, 3, 2, 5, 9, 5, 7, 8),nrow=3,ncol=3,byrow=TRUE)    
b <- matrix(data=c(20, 100, 200),nrow=3,ncol=1,byrow=FALSE)
solve(A)%*% b
```

Note that this is a square matrix!

Comment: how is this substantively different from the previously posted answers?  (note that `solve(A,b)` is equivalent to but more efficient than `solve(A) %*% b`)